# Rails - adding variable to JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, elasticsearch

I'm using this method to pass back outfits from an ajax call:

```
def givemeoutfits
  if current_user
    @outfits =  Outfit.search(params[:search],1000000,1,1000000,1,1000000,1,1000000,1).page(1).per(7).results
    @results = Outfit.search(params[:search],1000000,1,1000000,1,1000000,1,1000000,1).page(1).per(7).results.total_count
    if request.xhr?
      render status: 200, json: @outfits
  end
end 
end
```

I want to add the integer 'results' to the json produced by the @outfits and returned to the ajax call. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just wanting to include `@results` in the returned JSON object, like this?

```
render status: 200, json: {
  outfits: @outfits,
  results: @results
}
```

Then, in your javascript, you can interact with both keys.

Comment: Sure thing, best of luck! If this answer cleared everything up, would you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Sure - how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks! You should see a checkmark to the left of my answer, if I remember, that lets you mark it as "accepted". Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!